# set different limit on each tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying fetch each user's info and user's number from PHP database. So, the problem is that sometimes user adds more than 1 number. HERE is tables and SQL:

`users table`

```
id user_name email
1   John    john@gmail.com
2   David   david@gmail.com
```

`numbers table`

```
id  user_id   number    number_prefix
1     1        3144425      123
2     1        5484248      123
3     1        3144425      325
4     2        5991599      123
```

As you see, 1st user's have 3 number.

Here is my sql:

```
SELECT
  u.*,
  n.*
FROM
 users u,
 numbers n
WHERE
 u.id = n.user_id AND
 u.id = 1
```

OF course it will work. I want to set different LIMIT for each tables. I mean to set LIMIT 1 for table: users, and set LIMIT 3 for table: numbers

To do it, I used another sql, like below:

```
SELECT *,

    (
    SELECT
        number
    FROM
        menu
    WHERE
        user_id = 1
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT 0,3) AS number

FROM users
WHERE id = 1
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 0,1
```

As you know sub query can not return more than 1 row Maybe, IT should be better TO use SQL JOIN and GROUP BY... I have tried, but was not any good result...

Comment: Why do you need a limit on the `users` table? There's only 1 row with `id = 1`.

Comment: As i Know Sql will continue find next row without Limit. If sql find the row with limit 1, it will begin to stop the fetching process.

Comment: If the `id` field is indexed, it will not have to keep looking for more rows.

Comment: indexed? You mean auto increment?

Comment: As in `CREATE INDEX`. If it's the primary key of the table, it automatically gets an index. Also, the primary key is required to be unique, so it knows there can only be 1 match.

Comment: mmmmm I didn't know it, thank you for information. So, if I have 100000 users with indexed id, which method would you recommend? your sql or mine 1st sql?

Comment: The difference is negligible, since it's only dealing with a join between 3 and 1 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the subqueries in a join, then it can return multiple rows.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT number
      FROM menu
      WHERE user_id = 1
      ORDER BY id
      LIMIT 3) AS number,
JOIN (SELECT *
      FROM users
      WHERE id = 1
      LIMIT 1) AS users
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     SELECT * 

      FROM (SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1) AS us , numbers ns 

      WHERE us.id = '1' LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: please add some information abou your solution and how it solves the problem and what the questioner was missing or doing wrong.